# Subversion Merging

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

I have a trunk that contains the current release code with various bug fixes in it and a branch that contains various new features for the next release of the system. I'm trying to merge the bug fixes from the trunk into the branch ready for testing but I'm coming across some problems.

I'm using AnkhSVN and selecting the option "Merge a range of revisions". Two problems are presented

- "No uncommitted modifications"
- "No switched children"

I have no pending changes. Could this be an issue with other users having uncommitted changes?

Comment: In the end I just didn't use the safety checks and it worked fine. But I'd still like to know what Ankh was complaining about

Answer (score 1):

"No uncommited modifications" usually means that there are pending changes. It could be that either the switched working copy causes the message to come up, or that there are uncommitted modifications not in Pending Changes. To check for this run:

```
svn status -q c:\path\to\workingcopy
```

"No switched children" means that you have a switched working copy, this means that there's at least one directory 'connected' to a different branch in the working copy than the root directory of the working copy. To fix this, you have to switch the root of the working copy to the branch again. Unfortunately AnkhSVN doesn't allow you to do this (yet). You can run the command line client something like:

```
svn switch <reposurl>/branches/correctbranch c:\path\to\workingcopy
```

Answer (score 0):

Sander is right, "No switched children" means you might have a branch created from the one you are trying to merge to which has some blockers.

If you use Eclipse, you can go back to your branch and check the "Merge Results" tab and undo any unwanted merge:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Also, you can check the "SVN Tree" tab for any conflicts on the folders structure:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Correct all inconsistencies, conflicts or any wrong merge, then you can go to trank, in your case, and try the merge again.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kT7i.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI0Gf.png

Answer (score -2):

One possibility is your working copy is trunk.